# Typo in the new post activity div on SO and title on other SE sites

Tags: bug, live-refresh, grammar, plurals

The new post activity div which gives info about the number of questions on Stack Overflow says

> 1 new question**s**

[image]

This is grammatically incorrect, but only in the case of 1 question; if there are more than one questions, of course this phrase is grammatically correct.

Also, this is only in the case of SO. On other sites this div seems to be working okay (because they are still on the old navigation for me perhaps?).

However on other sites, the title of the question seems to be incorrect.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: [I'd watch out for any giant "S" near you in the future](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105).

Comment: "If there are more than one question" is also grammatically incorrect. And not to mention it's not ever been "Stackoverflow". And do you ever see "(2) Inboxes" if you have Gmail open?

Comment: @random (1) thanks edited (2) Sorry I didn't understand what you meant when you said *And not to mention it's not ever been "Stackoverflow"* (3) My understanding was that the title was Inbox and the count represented the number of unread emails.